# TDD solution architecture best practice

Tags: c#, architecture, tdd, testdriven.net

How will be the solution architecture of TDD project. I mean how should I design a test project?

I have to write a test project for an already existing developed MVC project. I will enhance some of the new feature. This will be the first time for this project to develop new feature using TDD approach. Is there any convention that I should follow?

Should I create a separate test application, then write some test class, methods. Then implement the actual functionality in the same test project or in the original project where new feature will be implemented.

Another thing I need to know, is there any specific convention for naming classes,methods, variable? I will use MS test and for mocking MOQ.

Comment: `"Then implement the actual functionality in the same test project or in the original project where new feature will be implemented."` - I don't understand at all what you mean by this statement.  TDD would imply simply that you have tests which validate the current functionality, then you add/modify tests to test for the new functionality (these tests will initially fail because the new functionality doesn't exist yet), then you modify the code to pass the tests, then refactor as needed using the passing tests as a baseline.  It's not really clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Say I will write a feature that will sum two number. So initially I write test case for sum method. But I didn't actually create the sum method yet. So it will fail. Now I need to create the sum method. 
So now where I will create the sum method? In the test project then move it after final testing  or in the actual project.

Comment: You'd create the method where it needs to be created.  I can't think of any reason to create it anywhere else.  It sounds like you're trying to artificially over complicate things.

Answer (score 4):

- Create new Test solution with one Test project (suggested name for test project `<OriginalProject>.Tests` - thanks to @ReneA)
- Add your original project as `Existing project` to the test solution
- Add reference of original project to the test project
- Create same folder/namespace structure as in original project. This will help navigating in both projects - thanks to @ReneA
- Create new Test class
- Add new test method where you will call a method from original project and assert results

Do not waste time with naming in the beginning. Start writing tests, run them. After few tests you will be able to find out by yourself what naming conventions is more suitable for your project.

Comment: For naming I'd suggest a few guidelines to start, For test project names use the same name with a suffix of .Tests (MyProject is tested by MyProject.Tests). Use the same folder/namespace structure as n the original. (MyProject.NameSpaceA is tested by MyProject.Tests.NamespaceA). This will ensure you can quickly find the test class for the class you're working on.

Comment: I have read from some tutorial that first of all I have to write the test case first. So it will fail, as there is no implementation for the newly created feature. Then I have to write the new methods or code, where should I write them?

Say I will write a feature that will sum two number. So initially I write test case for sum method. But I didn't actually create the sum method yet. So it will fail. Now I need to create the sum method. So now where I will create the sum method? In the test project then move it after final testing or in the actual project.